# Dismiss a previous Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, segue, viewcontroller

I am current developing an game with multiple viewcontroller. 
VC1(intro) -> VC2(game selection) ->VC3,VC4,VC5(games) -> VC6(display marks)

all the arrows are modal segue

I use unwind segue to go back from VC6 to VC2 and would like to replay. However, when select a game to go to VC3, the VC3 is not brand new as expected. It appears as the finished game condition.

If I really want to replay it after showing the marks, how can I achieve this with segue and Viewcontroller?

Moreover, how can I completely remove the instance of a previous viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go back on the `parentViewController` chain:

```
UIViewController *viewController = nil;
do {
    viewController = self.parentViewController;
} while (![self isViewControllerImLookingFor:viewController]);
```

Or you could implement a custom navigation stack manager, and store an array of navigation controllers, similar to how `UINavigationController` does.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the view controller array of your navigation controller like so

```
NSMutableArray *navigarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[navigarray removeLastObject]; //navigarray contains all vcs
[[self navigationController] setViewControllers:navigarray animated:YES];
```

Comment: I am not using navigation controller. All of the viewcontroller are not  navigation.